# How to split a String containing multiple groups of string into Sets of Set in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a String that contains multiple groups of string, each group is wrapped in brackets {}.  Each group is separated by comma and each string with a group is also separated by comma.  The format is something like:

```
  {abc,  def}, {006,  xy,  036}, {......}
```

What I want to do is to put each group into a HashSet, and another HashSet contains all those sets, something like:

```
  set 1:  abc
          def

  set 2:  006
          xy
          036
   .....
  set n:

  allSets --> set1, set2, set...., setn.
```

What I can think of now is to iterate each char in the original string and add it to the set(s).  But I wonder if there are other ways to do it, or if Java has some APIs that can accomplish this.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are looking for a simple parser. But it's probably easier to hack this up the usual way than to write one.

Comment: @mszymborski  Can you please be more clear on " hack this up the usual way than to write one" ?  what is the usual way ?

Comment: You can write a neat stream to cut it up, trim, remove all the unnecessary bits. A lot of work and a pain in the ass to modify later on, but still simpler than learning antlr.

Comment: @mszymborski  I don't have Java 1.8 though for stream.....

Comment: And I've just finished cutting it up :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String str="{abc,  def}, {006,  xy,  036}";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

It will give you values like

> abc,  def
>   006,  xy,  036

Now you can go ahead and add it accordingly into the string array or map, Its a hack around.

Comment: You can use lazy regexes instead of using the `[^}]` thing

Comment: where you will use that?

Comment: `*` usually matches as many tokens as possible - if you use `*?` it's going to match as little tokens as possible (but will still find a match if there's one) - for example `\\{(.*?)\\}`